# Showing previously scanned page when scanning several pages

Tags: catalina, pdf, preview, scanning

The scanner window allows us to combine multiple pages in a single PDF document. However, unless one clicks the <kbd>Overview</kbd> button before every scanning, the last scanned page is not displayed on the left hand side (the blank area in the image below).

[image]

When scanning a big document, say 40 or 50 pages, it's easy to lose track of the progress (in that case, the solution is opening the PDF in Finder and checking its last page).

My question is: is there any settings or any way to show the last scanned page, or is this a limitation of the program? As an additional info I'm using Catalina and AirPrint (but using the scanner's drivers gives the same behaviour, no difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Preview>File>Import from [name of scanner]. You get the exact same scanning window; it's also a Mac OS built-in program; and you can see the thumbnails of the few most recent scans along with the full size of any page you like with the page-up or page-down buttons.

Comment: That's a good workaround.